# Inserting Row into Database using HTML/PHP/AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sql-insert

I have a button that can be clicked that will bring up a popup box with one textfield. Whenever, I enter something and click "Add", I want it to be inserted into my database.

Currently, when I click "Add", it will insert into the DB, but it will not read the value entered. Therefore, a null value is simply entered. I get no errors that I can see, however in my JavaScript I do a `console.log(dict)` and the output in the log is `Object {}` so it doesn't look like the entered value is being logged. I also am getting a successful row inserted message in the logs too so I would definitely think that it is just a matter of being able to get the values to be read.

So my question is how can I get it to read the value and successfully enter it into the database.

HTML of Add button:

```
<td><button class="create-user" id="insertButton">Add Group</button></td>
```

HTML of Popup Box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Group">
  <p class="validateTips">Please Add a Group</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>        

      <label for="sku_group">SKU Group</label>
      <input type="text" name="group" id="group" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">


      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Dialog Box for adding a row -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      sku_group = $( "#group" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( sku_group ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }


   function addGroup() {

      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( sku_group, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid SKU Group name" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#skuTable tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+sku_group );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "group":
                dict["SKU Group"] = value;
            break;
            }
        });
        $( "#skuTable tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-group.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });

}

      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Group": addGroup,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addGroup();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });

  });
```

insert-group.php script:

```
<?php

  $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO SKU_Group_Dim ([SKU Group]) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($SKU_Group));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

EDIT

My html table:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Group ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($sql_table) as $rows) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $rows['SKU Group']?></td>
            <td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($rows['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $rows['Group_ID']?></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="edit" name="edit">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the output of console.log(type + " : " + value); (inside .each function?

Comment: I'm not getting an output for that for some reason

Comment: check my answer below. I think it's not working because each does not iterate and the program just jumps over it

Comment: Yes just realized that...the output is `undefined : `

Comment: I've updated the answer. from what I've gathered you want to iterate over all the tr there and get their value and type?

Comment: updated the answer. I get the output. although I wasn't sure why you use $(this).val() - what do you want to get with it? Ive changed it to .html()

Comment: updated answer again. hope comments and examples help to get what you want

Answer (score 1):

Your value does not good 
Try to change

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

To

```
var value = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
```

Comment: Please share me the content of the object or the console error. if not send me the return of console.log(type + " : " + value); 
thanks

Comment: I am not getting any errors....there is no content in the object, the only thing i see in the console is `object {}`...and also for whatever reason, i am not getting anything in my console for `console.log(type + " : " + value);`

Comment: Fixed something in my code thanks to boroboris....my output for the console.log is now `undefined : `

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$.each` function to `$tr.each`. I think you should provide something for it to iterate over. Here is the [link to .each() documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/each/).
If you want to iterate over all 's you have to add td to jquery call.

My fix would look like this:

```
    var $tr = $( "#skuTable tbody tr td" ).eq(0).clone();  //get all td of sku-table
    var dict = {};
    $tr.each(function(){
      var type = $(this).attr('id');    // get value of current tr
      var value = $(this).html();       // get html content inside of tr

      switch (type) {
        case "group":
            dict["SKU Group"] = value;
            break;
        }
    });

    $('#group').val(dict['SKU Group']);  // set value of the input field
```

Comment: how does your table look like?

Comment: I just updated my original post to include my table as well

Comment: my new output of the `console.log(type + " : " + value);` is now `sku_group-0 : `

Comment: yes, but now this function is iterating over tr elements. you just need to fetch information you need. and I'm still not sure which info exactly do you need? id from sku_group and html from the group tr?

Comment: I need the info from this line of code inside of my popup box `<input type="text" name="group" id="group" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">`